# Remove domain user access to ubuntu machine

Tags: windows, sudo, domain-server

I have configured my Ubuntu server to allow login using Windows AD credentials.
I have added enabled a domain group to login to ubuntu machine(by adding them in sudoer file)

`#%mydomain\\domain^users ALL=(ALL) ALL`

Now I want to remove the login access of these group members to the machine. 
I tried modifying sudoer(removed `#%mydomain\\domain^users ALL=(ALL) ALL` )

But still the users of that group  is able to login.

How can I remove the access.

Answer (score 1):

To enable access to one group only to ubuntu run the below command

`sudo lwconfig RequireMembershipOf "Domain\testusers"`

the above command only allows testusers group to login to the machine.

In my case I am using `likewise-open` to enable admin access